# chrome headless bypass certification on terminal

Tags: google-chrome, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I want to run chrome with --headless option on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS pc, I use https protocol.
This is the command:

```
$ /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --allow-running-insecure-content --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-gpu --headless https://<APP_IP>
```

And this is the response:

```
[0718/105254.243715:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(923)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for <APP_IP> failed err=-8172
```

Info: I use Google Chrome 59.0.3071.115

Could you give me any advice to bypass certicate errors?

Thakns in advance

Comment: Try `--ignore-certificate-errors` and `--reduce-security-for-testing`

Comment: This error caused by new (invalid ?!) libnss3.so binary. 
I had same problem with Chrome and I changed libnss3.so library from /usr/lib/firefox/libnss3.so (Chrome read from this path) with old version (firefox 51).

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are no plans from the Chrome team to support `--ignore-certificate-errors`.

Source: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/headless-dev/eiudRsYdc3A